# Paste image from clipboard no longer works in Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, clipboard

In Trello and Slack, it is possible to paste images from clipboard and have them uploaded. I used to do this in Chrome and I can still do it in Firefox - but no longer in Chrome.

I have tried googling for solutions, but have been unsuccessful so far. Is there a setting or something, I need to change, to get this working again?

I am on Win10 and latest Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Seems an extension was the culprit, maybe...

I disabled all extensions, then paste image upload worked again. Then I re-enabled extensions one by one and tested - and after re-enabling all of them, it still worked!?

Anyway - works now, and if you face the same problem, look to your extensions.